# Building copies of keilim from the Beis Hamikdash

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, menorah--in-temple

The Gemara [Avodah Zara .מג](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.43a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> **לא יעשה אדם** בית תבנית היכל אכסדרה תבנית אולם חצר תבנית עזרה שולחן תבנית שולחן **מנורה תבנית מנורה** אבל הוא עושה של ה' ושל ו' ושל ח' ושל ז' לא יעשה אפילו של שאר מיני מתכות רבי יוסי בר יהודה אומר אף של עץ לא יעשה כדרך שעשו בית חשמונאי
>
> **A person may not construct** a house in the exact image of the Sanctuary, nor a portico in the exact image of the Entrance Hall of the Sanctuary, nor a courtyard corresponding to the Temple courtyard, nor a table corresponding to the Table in the Temple, nor **a candelabrum corresponding to the Candelabrum in the Temple.** But one may fashion a candelabrum of five or of six or of eight lamps. And one may not fashion a candelabrum of seven lamps even if he constructs it from other kinds of metal rather than gold, as in extenuating circumstances the Candelabrum in the Temple may be fashioned from other metals. Rabbi Yosei bar Yehuda says: One may not fashion a candelabrum of wood either, in the manner that the kings of the Hasmonean monarchy fashioned it. When they first purified the Temple they had to fashion the Candelabrum out of wood as no other material was available. Since a wooden candelabrum is fit for the Temple, it is prohibited to fashion one of this kind for oneself.
> (Sefaria)

This is also brought down in Halacha in [Yoreh De'ah ס'קמא ס'ח](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.141.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Rambam בית הבחירה ז:י](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Chosen_Temple.7.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).
The [Pischei Teshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.141.8?lang=bi&with=Pitchei%20Teshuva&lang2=en) brings the Bechor Shor that

> חדשים מקרוב באו עושים כוונים למלאכת מנורת המקדש בשינוי ממידת הקנים דהיינו שעושים ז' קנים וששה מהם מעמידים בדמות עיגול או משולש או מרובע אלו נגד אלו וא' באמצע דיש למחות בידם

The Pischei Teshuva also points out that based off of Tos. that this is an Issur Di'oraysa.
The [Minchas Chinuch  רנד:סוף ו](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14092&st=&pgnum=38&hilite=) [(יג)](https://tablet-otzar-org.eu1.proxy.openathens.net/book/book.php?book=147652&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16387608095004992&pagenum=281) mentions that this Issur applies to some of the other Keilim in the Beis Hamikdash.
[Igros Moshe Yoreh De'ah ס'לג](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=267&hilite=) points out that this Issur would not apply to a menorah that can't hold the correct shiur of oil. R' Moshe also wants to say that the Issur would not apply to a menorah that is made to teach.

I recall that when I was previously in Eretz Yisrael I had seen a life-sized Menorah. I found that [The Temple Institute](https://templeinstitute.org/history-holy-temple-menorah/) was the maker. They hope that this Menorah will be used in the 3rd Beis Hamikdash (see [here](https://www.jpost.com/Israel/CITYsights-More-than-a-model-menorah) and [here](https://templeinstitute.org/menorah-mystery-and-daily-service/))

Are there any reasons why this Issur Di'oraysa would not apply to creating this Menorah? If not, have any Rabbonim tried to protest this?

Comment: I'm confused. If we can't make kelim to be used in the Temple, what kelim will we use?

Comment: The point is that one cannot make a menorah to be used in a secular manner. The gemarah says that one can make a menorah to teach how to use the menorah in the Bais Hamikdash

Answer (score 1):

It is not made as a copy, but to actually be used

Comment: The OP knows this and mentions it in the question

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, it falls under (their) מנורה תבנית מנורה

Comment: @mbloch, so the OP answered his own question. Rav Hershel Schachter told me the same thing. See https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/949009/